# How do I access the length of an array that is an argument in a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm going through Eloquent Javascript, and I'm running into some trouble with array.length.

```js
let arrayToList = (array) => {
  let i = (array.length - 1);
  if (array[i] === 0) {
    return {value: array[i], rest: null};
  } else {
    return {value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array[i - 1])};
  }
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```

When I run this, I get an error saying that I "cannot read property 'length' of undefined".
This next function does work. Why will the above function not allow for access of the argument array's length?

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```

**P.S.** I'm not even sure if the first function works like the second; however, I just want to know why I can't seem to access the argument array's length.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (i === 0) {` instead of `if (array[i] === 0) {`?

Comment: you end up passing an item to your recursive call meaning in the next call you wont have an array,.

Comment: The recursive call should be `arrayToList(array.slice(0, -1))`, passing an array, instead of `arrayToList(array[i - 1])`. (Although I think you're constructing the linked list backwards)

Comment: Btw the recursion base case should be `array.length === 0`, not `array[i] === 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array[i - 1])
```

The problem is in this line. You’re calling `arrayToList` with an integer, not an array. That’s leading to unexpected behaviour, since the function expects an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what structure you actually want, but if you want to recurse with the "rest" being the remainder then it likely looks a lot more like this:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  let i = (array.length - 1);

  // If there's no array left to work with...
  if (i <= 0) {
    return { value: array[i], rest: null };
  }

  // Call "rest" as the remaining elements in the array
  return { value: array[i], rest: arrayToList(array.slice(0, i)) };
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30,40,42]));
console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
console.log(arrayToList([10]));
console.log(arrayToList([]));
```

Where that can deal with arrays of various lengths.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Notice that the list is still backwards, as compared to the iterative version.

Comment: @Bergi That's how I interpreted "rest". The inverse form is pretty easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

Got me a while to finish this but here it is using `Array.pop()` and `Array.reverse()`, try the snippet to check the output.

```js
let arrayToList = (array) => {
if (typeof array !== 'undefined') {
array = array.reverse();
let current = array.pop();
let length = array.length;
  if (length === 0) {
    return {value: current, rest: null};
  } else {
    return {value: current, rest: arrayToList(array)};
  }
}
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```